# How to access the charge of an ion?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a Python program that returns the ionic charge of the entered atomic number with some extra information. I only have problems with accessing the ionic charge of an element. Other information codes are working properly.

How can I do it?

You can see the code below:

```
from mendeleev import element

while True:
    aNum=int(input("Please enter the atomic number:\t"))

    if aNum<0 or aNum>118:
        print("\nPlease enter a valid atomic number!\n")

    else:
        break

e=element(aNum)
n=e.name
s=e.symbol
#The problem occurs at the line below.
c=e.charge
#The problem occurs at the line above.

print("""Information about the element that has atomic number {} is below:
 \nName:          {}
 Symbol:          {}
 Ionic Charge:    {}""".format(aNum,n,s,c))
```

Error is like that:

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'charge'
```

From now, thanks!

Comment: There is an error. I don't have an output.

Comment: Bu arada Türk isen Türkçe yazabilirsin ;)

Comment: Elements have no charge. You're looking for `mendeleev.ion`.

Comment: You can see all attributes of `e` with `dir(e)`. You will see there is no `e.charge` attribute, as the error clearly states.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a quick look at the [documentation](https://mendeleev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/notebooks/quick_start.html) gave me this,

```
from collections import Counter 
charges = []
for ir in e.ionic_radii:
    charges.append(ir.charge)
print(charges)
print(Counter(charges).most_common(1)[0][0]) #most occuring charge
```

Output:

```
Please enter the atomic number: 8
[-2, -2, -2, -2, -2]
-2
```

The ionic_radii function also contains certain other values such as spin, origin etc as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, but is there a way that I can only get the "charge" value?

Comment: So you want all the charge values like in the output ive given or say the highest charge vaue?

Comment: Only the 1 is enough for me. E.g  O= -2  or  H=(+)1 . Signs of ionic charges are not necessary except the charge is negative.

Comment: I have updated the code. But what you do do in the case of multiple charges, select the most occurring one?

Comment: Thank you very much! That's which I was looking for. Answer to your question, if you mean elements like Carbon I will take it like +-4, but I found answer to my question so you don't need to add that to the program.

Comment: You're the best! I can't find a word for your great efforts to help me. Thank you very very much!

Comment: You're welcome mate. Also you may upvote if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more *Pythonic* version of your code, which does what you expected:

```py
from mendeleev import element
from mendeleev.ion import Ion


while True:
    atomic_number = int(input("Please enter the atomic number: "))

    if 0 < atomic_number < 119:
        break
    else:
        print("Please enter a valid atomic number!")

e = element(atomic_number)

charges = [_.charge for _ in e.ionic_radii]

print(f'''
Information about the element that has atomic number {atomic_number} is below:
\tName:         {e.name}
\tSymbol:       {e.symbol}
\tIonic Charge: {Ion(atomic_number)} {charges}
''')
```

And here is a sample outputs:

```
Please enter the atomic number: 1

Information about the element that has atomic number 1 is below:
    Name:         Hydrogen
    Symbol:       H
    Ionic Charge: H⁺ [1, 1]

Please enter the atomic number: 8

Information about the element that has atomic number 8 is below:
    Name:         Oxygen
    Symbol:       O
    Ionic Charge: O⁺ [-2, -2, -2, -2, -2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much too! That is also similar to which I was looking for.